# React router 4 only works in main module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm struggling with react route 4, trying to guess why it only works in main module.

My code:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Enterprise from './containers/Enterprise'
import Provider from './containers/Provider'
import Home from './containers/Home'

let render = () => {

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>   
       <div>
         <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route exact path="/enterprises" component={Enterprise} >
            <Route exact path="/providers" component={Provider} />
         </Switch>                         
      </div>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  )
} 

render()
```

This will stop working as soon as I declare the Routes inside AppContainer (living in a separated file). Like:

AppContainer.js

```
imports...

class AppContainer extends Component {

  shouldComponentUpdate () {
    return false
  }

  render () {

    return (
        <Header />

        <Sidebar /> 

        <main>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route exact path="/enterprises" component={Enterprise} >
            <Route exact path="/providers" component={Provider} />
          </Switch> 
        </main>

        <Footer />
    )
  }
}

export default AppContainer
```

main.js

```
imports...

let render = () => {

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>   
        <AppContainer />          
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  )
}
```

I'm using webpack modules, but not using code splitting so... I'm confused. I searched the web there's a lot of examples of this working in separated modules (even if the source code in shown in a single file).

Any clue?

Comment: Is `AppContainer` by any chance a react-hot-loading component? If so I think that's what's wrong. Put `<App />` `inside AppContainer` and `Router` inside `App`.

Comment: Yes, I have hot-reloading. And I have a <Page /> component inside AppContainer. Actually that's were I wish to render my pages, so that's where I'm trying to define my routes (or at least pass them as props, but none of the two attempts works).

Comment: So, i disabled HMR and it won't work either.

Comment: Do you import Router in AppContainer?

Comment: Thanks for the questions and comments. I think I'd just overlook my code, and shouldComponentUpdate() was causing the issue (I updated my original code to reflect that, sorry it wasn't present when I first published). Well, i don't know if it was that, but using a constant instead worked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems like the problem was shouldComponentUpdate(). I'm using a constant now and it works.

AppContainer.js

imports...

```
    const AppContainer = () => (

      <div className="page-wrapper">

          <Header />

          <div className="page-container">   

              <Sidebar />

                <main>           
                  <Switch>          
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />   
                    <Route exact path="/enterprises" component={Enterprise} >
                    <Route exact path="/providers" component={Provider} />          
                  </Switch> 
                </main>                                               
          </div>

          <Footer />

      </div>  
)
```

(btw, that  block actually goes in another file component named Page. I'm just simplifying my code here)

Comment: A comment about the down-vote would be appreciated. I'm new with react and react-router and I really researched a lot about the issue. So, I did my best.